# box-sizing: border-box not working with Cleanslate.css

Tags: html, css

I'm using [Cleanslate](https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate) to reset all the CSS attributes on my widget container and its children, and I'm trying to add `box-sizing: border-box` to all of my elements, but it's not behaving as expected.

The anchor element (set to `display: inline-block`) with 100% width doesn't subtract its padding/margin from the width. I have a Codepen that shows the behavior I'm seeing here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXarGy.

Could someone please help me figure out what's going on here? I'm not all that great with CSS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I'm expecting the margin to be subtracted from the width of the container, so I'll have a margin on each side of each link. However, as the answer below points out, this is not how `border-box` works. My ignorance of CSS is to blame here...sorry, I should've done more research rather than assuming my mental model was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boder-box` isn't supposed to subtract margin.

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp):

> The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin

So it seems like your example is working as expected as you are setting a margin:

```
margin: 12px 20px !important;
```

that is added to your `width: 100%;`

Also see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) about box-sizing.

Comment: I see, thank you. Sorry for my ill-informed question -- I still have a lot to learn, and I should have done more research rather than assume my mental model was correct. Thanks for helping me learn.